# Swift function alias

Tags: swift, alias

How can I create an alias for a function in swift?

For example

I want to call

```
LocalizedString("key")
```

and it should call

```
NSLocalizedString("key", comment:"")
```

I saw `typealias` command but it looks like it works only for types.

Comment: can you create a new function that will call NSLocalizedString?

Comment: Hm, I was wondering if there another way... like using a macro or something

Comment: The `comment` is put in the localized strings file and is very useful for the translator, even if it is only for you. It makes it easier to remember what that string is intended for. Not an anwer for your question though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Functions are named closures, so you can just assign a function to a variable:

```
let LocalizedString = NSLocalizedString
```

You can create pseudo-aliases for class/struct methods as well. Each method is actually a static (class) curried function, taking a class instance as its first parameter. So given a class:

```
class MyClass {
    var data: Int

    init(data: Int) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func test() {
        println("\(data)")
    }
}
```

you can assign the `test` method to a variable:

```
let test = MyClass.test
```

and then invoke it as:

```
var instance = MyClass(data: 10)
test(instance)()
```

---

**UPDATE**

I've just realized that I missed one important detail in your question: you want to hide the `comment` parameter. And my proposed solution doesn't allow that, whereas @rintaro's solution does.

However I use a different approach for that: I create a `String` extension implementing a computed property:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}
```

and then I can just call it on any string variable or literal:

```
var string = "test_resource"
string.localized

"another_resource".localized
```

Comment: thanks! I liked the extension idea but maybe it's a little forced wrapping for the function, what do you think?

Comment: @danielgomezrico No. It's fine. Just make sure to combine these functions in a file where you keep several String methods together, e.g., `String+Util.swift`

Comment: On the other hand, since `NSLocalized` is a global method (essentially), you might want to go that way instead.

Answer (score 11):

The shortest one is:

```
let LocalizedString = { NSLocalizedString($0, comment:"") }
```

But, it's actually a new function. Just wrapping `NSLocalizedString`.

---

Maybe you can use undocumented `@transparent` attribute. It inlines function call. see [this topic on Developer Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/988972#988972).

```
@transparent LocalizedString(key:String) -> String {
    return LocalizedString(key, comment:"")
}
```

But it's not recommended. Moreover, as long as my tests, all of following codes eventually emit exact the same LLVM IR code with `-O` optimization.

**script1**: with `@transparent`

```
import Foundation
@transparent func LocalizedString(key:String) -> String {
    return LocalizedString(key, comment:"")
}
println(LocalizedString("key"))
```

**script2**: without `@transparent`

```
import Foundation
func LocalizedString(key:String) -> String {
    return LocalizedString(key, comment:"")
}
println(LocalizedString("key"))
```

**script3**: Direct `NSLocalizedString` call

```
import Foundation
func LocalizedString(key:String) -> String {
    return LocalizedString(key, comment:"")
}
println(NSLocalizedString("key", comment:""))
```

All of above are inlined to perform direct `NSLocalizedString` call.

But, the following code emits different:

**script4**: Closure wrapping

```
import Foundation
let LocalizedString = { NSLocalizedString($0, comment:"") }
println(NSLocalizedString("key", comment:""))
```

It's also inlined, but additional `refcount` instruction to `LocalizedString` is inserted.

So, as a conclusion, you should simply use this:

```
func LocalizedString(key:String) -> String {
    return LocalizedString(key, comment:"")
}
```

Comment: What do you men with inlined and inserted?